# how to create and control a java telegram bot in spring web mvc

Tags: java, spring, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I need to create a java telegram bot and control it by a web application that i want to use spring web mvc. I test some os codes not web one that work properly but i could not find any help for web one. 
please help me.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood you in the correct way, but I can offer you to control the bot with http calls. I saw an example of this here https://github.com/pengrad/java-telegram-openshift
Pay attention at Main.java